# С++, не присваиваются значения глобальных inline переменных

Tags: c++

Переменные объявлены в .h файле, этот файл подключается только один раз. Сам .h файл - API файл библиотеки .so, которая динамически линкуется к бинарнику.
При присваивании им значения оно не устанавливается.

Пример объявления:

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))
inline EXPORT std::filesystem::path  g_config_path;
```

gdb:

```
108     g_run_path = "/run/" NT_VENDOR;
(gdb) n
109     g_var_path = "/var/lib/" NT_VENDOR;
(gdb) p g_run_path
$6 = filesystem::path ""
(gdb) n
110 }
(gdb) p g_var_path
$7 = filesystem::path ""

276                 PARSE_NUMBER_OPT(g_proc_id); # В макросе устанавливается значение g_proc_id из optarg
(gdb) p optarg 
$9 = 0x7fffffffe2ca "1"
(gdb) n
277                 break;
(gdb) p g_proc_id
$10 = {_value = 0 '\000', _has_value = false}

377         g_config_path = fs::absolute(cfgfile, ec);
(gdb) p cfgfile
$11 = 0x7fffffffe288 "./example.conf"
(gdb) n
378         if (ec)
(gdb) p g_config_path
$12 = filesystem::path ""
```

И так далее.

Из-за чего такое может быть?

Comment: Сделайте тест без gbd. Распечатайте пути прямо из программы. Чутьё подсказывает что в gdb как-то плохо сконфигурировано отображение переменных именно этого класса.

Comment: Для экспорта сделайте переменную extern. А еще лучше геттер. А то сейчас переменная inline и вставляется в каждую единицу трансляции, где используется.

Comment: @user7860670, это как-то может быть связано с работой отладчика?

Comment: Нет, это совершенно никак не связано с работой отладчика.

Comment: Сделал тест. Локально GDB нормально всё отображает. Ищите проблемы в сборке.

Comment: @user7860670, мне не даёт покоя вот что: пусть переменная криво объявлена. Почему отладчик внутри одной единицы трансляции не видит её изменений?

Comment: Что-то с отладчиком, вывод значений через `printf` отрабатывает нормально.

Comment: Чтобы в отладчике смотреть надо кастовать адрес этой переменной из библиотеки или из текущей единицы трансляции, а не по имени.